# SQL: Compound Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to form a query where table1.first_name + " " + table1.last_name matches table2.customer_name?

IE:
customers.first_name = "John"
customers.last_name = "Doe"

orders.customer_name = "John Doe"

It seems to me this would be a common query, but just can't come up with the syntax intuitively.

Also, I am led to believe that this would not be a 'best practice' solution (using id fields would be better), but if I can't control the schema, I just want to know if something like my approach is even possible.

Comment: You can join the customers table to the orders table on your criteria but know that it  will be riddled with errors.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: What do you do if you have two customers named `John Smith`?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `concat`

```
where concat(customers.first_name,' ',customers.last_name) = orders.customer_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the values and compare the result as so:

```
(customers.first_name || ' ' || customers.last_name) = orders.customer_name
```

Brackets only for readability

Comment: Apparently, you use '||' for concatination (not '+').  My bad.  My final solution that worked as I imagined was:



> SELECT * 
> FROM customers, sales
> WHERE customers.first_name || " " || customers.last_name = sales.customer_name
> ORDER BY sales.id;



Again, probably not best practice, but it's nice to know that it can be done, if needed...

Comment: @PeterVann glad to hear you found a solution. Welcome to SO! You should probably select either mine or isaace's answer as the correct answer. Isaace's seems a bit better tbh. Best luck learning